# Have any countries besides Germany announced plans to increase military aid to Ukraine? (Nov 2023)

Tags: ukraine, military, foreign-aid

[VOA](https://www.voanews.com/a/senior-eu-official-says-ukraine-artillery-pledge-won-t-be-met-by-march/7354292.html), Nov 14:

> German Chancellor Olaf Scholz's governing coalition has agreed in principle to double the country's military aid for Ukraine next year to about $8.5 billion, a political source in Berlin said Sunday.
>
> If approved by parliament, where Scholz's coalition holds a majority, the boost would lift Germany's defense spending to 2.1% of its gross domestic product, exceeding the 2% target pledged by all NATO members, the source added.

Have other countries announced an increase in military aid to Ukraine in the future, over their current levels?

Comment: https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/eus-20-billion-euro-plan-ukraine-military-aid-hits-resistance-2023-11-10/

Answer (score 6):

Reporting in the NYT lays out the future Ukraine funding plans from EU countries [Europe Moves to Fill Weapons Gap Amid Doubts About U.S. Commitment to Ukraine](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/11/18/world/europe/europe-military-aid-ukraine.html)

It reports that:

> Germany, Norway, Britain and others are increasing weapons production to help Kyiv.

Comment: I've added a short quote from the article to answer the question.  Otherwise this was a "Link only" answer and Many people won't be able to access the link, since NYT is paywalled. You can add more details, for example to describe how large these increases in weapon production are, and if the arms will be provided as "aid" or not.